# AWS Sagemaker on local machine: Invalid security token included in the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to get AWS Sagemaker to run locally. I found this jupyter notebook

https://gitlab.com/juliensimon/aim410/-/blob/master/local_training.ipynb

I logged into AWS via saml2aws and hence have valid credentials, entered my specific region as well as the Sagemaker Execution Role ARN and specify below the specific image I want to pull.
However when starting the .fit() i getthe following ClientError:
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Can someone give my a hint or suggestion how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify your AWS credentials are setup properly, bypassing Boto3, by running a cell with something like:

```
!aws sagemaker list-endpoints
```

If this fails, then your AWS CLI credentials aren't setup correctly, or your saml2aws process, or your role has no SageMaker permissions.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the problem, I had to specify my --profile then it worked, it previously always took the default credentials